# Mysql Select Second Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql question.

---

I have a news section on my website, and I want to display the two latest items.
If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

it selects the latest item,
and now I want to select the second to last item.

Do you guys know how to do it?

/// EDIT

Now it doesn't work, here's my code: (I have connect included ;) )

```
            $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
            $datum = $row['time'];
            $titel = $row['title'];
            $bericht = $row['message'];
            ?>
            <div class="entry">

                <span class="blue date"><?php echo "$datum"; ?></span>
                <h3><?php echo "$titel"; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo "$bericht"; ?></p> <br />
            </div><!-- end of entry --> <?php } ?>
            <?php 
            $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMI 1, 1");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)) {
                $datum = $row2['time'];
                $titel = $row2['title'];
                $bericht = $row2['message'];
                ?>
            <div class="entry">
                <span class="green date"><?php echo "$datum"; ?> </span>
                <h3><?php echo "$titel"; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo "$bericht"; ?></p>
            </div> <!-- end of entry --> <?php } ?>
        </div><!-- end of news -->
```

Comment: @Alexander why not make that an answer.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to get the latest two rows, or only the second latest row?

Comment: @Pekka, OK, posted it as an answer. Sometimes I hesitate to post an answer when it is too simple, because anyway somebody will be faster and we'll end with many similar answers. In fact, you can see it right now here. :)

Comment: How exactly it "doesn't work"? And, by the way, I'd suggest to post your update as a different question (providing more details of course) because it has nothing to do with the "select second row" question (which is already answered).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2` - selects last 2 items

`SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1` - selects only second item

Comment: It doesn't work, i get this error: 
mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: Yeah i can provide, check my first post ;)

Comment: It's strange. Code looks good. Have you tried execute query at the phpMyAdmin or something?

Comment: I found the problem! Your second query have mistake: write "LIMIT" instead "LIMI".

Answer (score 8):

`LIMIT` can take two arguments:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 1, 1
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to display the latest two items, then you can get both at the same time by limiting to 2 instead of 1. This means it's only one database hit to get the information you need.

```
SELECT * FROM nieuws
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 2
```

Or if you only want the second row, you can give an offset to the LIMIT, to tell it which row to start from, (Although if you get the first row in one query, then get the second in another, you're doing two database hits to get the data you want, which can affect performance).

```
SELECT * FROM nieuws
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1, 1
```

You can find out more information on how to use the LIMIT clause in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id1046762)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM table where id > (SELECT id FROM table order by id ASC limit 1,1) and id <= (select max(id) from table)

Comment: Fetch the data from 2nd row to last row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM promotion
WHERE id = 16037
ORDER BY RankID ASC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is over 12 years old) with existing answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].