# Second MySQL query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

Check this code:

```
            $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
            $datum = $row['time'];
            $titel = $row['title'];
            $bericht = $row['message'];
            ?>
            <div class="entry">

                <span class="blue date"><?php echo "$datum"; ?></span>
                <h3><?php echo "$titel"; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo "$bericht"; ?></p> <br />
            </div><!-- end of entry --> <?php } ?>
            <?php 
            $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMI 1, 1");
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select2)) {
                $datum = $row2['time'];
                $titel = $row2['title'];
                $bericht = $row2['message'];
                ?>
            <div class="entry">
                <span class="green date"><?php echo "$datum"; ?> </span>
                <h3><?php echo "$titel"; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo "$bericht"; ?></p>
            </div> <!-- end of entry --> <?php } ?>
        </div><!-- end of news -->
```

The first news item is displayed correctly,
by the second i get this error:

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

What's the problem?

Comment: If a query fails, mysql_query returns false, which is "not a valid mysql result resource". Modify you query call line so it reads: ` ... mysql_query("....") or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());` and you'll get the reason why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Select Second Row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280155/mysql-select-second-row)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMI 1, 1
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Comment: @Andre why you duplicate your question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280155/mysql-select-second-row)? I already answered it in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled limit, you're missing the final T

Answer (score 1):

DESC LIMI -> DESC LIMIT, a typo. Listen to the error messages!

```
            $select2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nieuws ORDER BY id DESC LIMI 1, 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

That error messages means your sql query failed. You should add some error checking code to display the mysql error when this happens.

```
if( !$select2 ) {
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

I wouldn't leave this in production code but it's useful for debugging your code.

Always a good idea to read the manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php